# How to create a complex scrolling view in iOS similar to yelp?

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, uicollectionview

Yelp has this View show up when you click on a specific restaurant or some event:

[image]

In the picture above there is the `Cascal` label, then `Write a Review` button, then three buttons (`Photo or Video`, `Check in`, `Bookmark`) all in a row, then a map, and some cells underneath (`Directions`, `Call`, `Explore the menu`, etc.).

How can you make a complex scrolling view similar to this (do you have to use a collection view or table view?)? Since in both a `tableview` and `collectionview` you are reusing the same cells again and again (with the same layout) so it is difficult to create a view with so many heterogeneous elements like in the picture above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table view and a bunch of different cell classes each with their unique design (XIB or Storyboard) and height.

Select the cell class and height depending on index path and let table view delegate methods return accordingly.

Very basic stuff actually.

You only reuse cell classes if you need to. In the Yelp example the Directions, Call, Explore the Menu and More Info cells may have used the same design because the layout seems to be identical, only the image and text differs.